# C: Segmentation fault on function pointer

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault error when trying to sort the structure by using pointer. I guess it makes problem in 'scanf_s' function in 'main()' since "Debug MSG 2" is not printed when it is executed. here is the full code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct contestant
{
    char *name;
    float height;
    int weight;
} ppl;

typedef int(*Funcptr)(ppl *, ppl *);

int namecmp(ppl *, ppl *);
int heightcmp(ppl *, ppl *);
int weightcmp(ppl *, ppl *);
void sort(Funcptr, Funcptr, Funcptr, ppl *, int);

int main()
{
    int i;
    int num;
    ppl *people;

    scanf_s("%d", &num);

    people = (ppl *)malloc(num * sizeof(ppl));

    printf("Debug MSG 1\n");

    for (i = 0; i<num; i++)
        scanf_s("%s %f %d", people[i].name, &(people[i].height), &(people[i].weight));

    printf("Debug MSG 2\n");

    sort(namecmp, heightcmp, weightcmp, people, num);
    sort(heightcmp, weightcmp, namecmp, people, num);
    sort(weightcmp, namecmp, heightcmp, people, num);

    free(people);
}

int namecmp(ppl *human1, ppl *human2)
{
    char *temp;

    if (strcmp(human1->name, human2->name) > 0)
    {
        temp = human1->name;
        human1->name = human2->name;
        human1->name = temp;
        return 1;
    }

    else if (strcmp(human1->name, human2->name) == 0)
        return 0;

    else
        return -1;
}

int heightcmp(ppl *human1, ppl *human2)
{
    float temp;

    if (human1->height > human2->height)
    {
        temp = human1->height;
        human1->height = human2->height;
        human2->height = temp;
        return 1;
    }

    else if (human1->height == human2->height)
        return 0;

    else
        return -1;
}

int weightcmp(ppl *human1, ppl *human2)
{
    int temp;

    if (human1->weight > human2->weight)
    {
        temp = human1->weight;
        human1->weight = human2->weight;
        human2->weight = temp;
        return 1;
    }

    else if (human1->weight > human2->weight)
        return 0;

    else
        return -1;
}

void sort(Funcptr func1, Funcptr func2, Funcptr func3, ppl *person, int number)
{
    int i, j;
    int res1, res2;

    for (i = 0; i<number - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j<number; j++)
        {
            res1 = func1((person + i), (person + j));

            if (res1 == 0)
            {
                res2 = func2((person + i), (person + j));

                if (res2 == 0)
                {
                    func3((person + i), (person + j));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i<number; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %.1f %d\n", (person + i)->name, (person + i)->height, (person + i)->weight);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `scanf_s("%s` need parameter of buffer size. see [scanf_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

you're mallocing the table of people all right

```
people = (ppl *)malloc(num * sizeof(ppl));
```

(except that you don't have to cast return of `malloc`, but that's a detail)

but that doesn't dispense you to allocate memory for your `name` member structure

```
for (i = 0; i<num; i++)
    scanf_s("%s %f %d", people[i].name, ...
```

Also as BLUEPIXY noticed, you're not using `scanf_s` properly (I thought it was `scanf`), you need to pass the max numbers of chars or simply use `scanf` with a size limitation.

fix it like that for instance:

```
for (i = 0; i<num; i++)
{
    people[i].name = malloc(51);
    scanf("%50s %f %d", people[i].name, ....
}
```

Alternate solution: define your structure as follows:

```
typedef struct contestant
{
    char name[50];
    float height;
    int weight;
} ppl;
```

so no need to `malloc` the name. Allocating the array of `ppl` like you did is enough.

Comment: `scanf_s("%50s %f %d", people[i].name,` --> `scanf_s("%49s %f %d", people[i].name, 50,`

Comment: fixed (not that it was the main problem anyway)

Comment: `%s` of `scanf_s` need size parameter as argument. see [scanf_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx). Also `char name[49];` --> `char name[50];`

Comment: I need some rest :) thanks. Now I realize that the crash could also come from the omission of the size in `scanf_s`: double error in the OP code.